# How do I make an object detect the nearest specific object in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So say there is a circle in some magical land, and there are 3 squares. One is very close, one is very far, and one is in the middle. The circle does not to feel to run that much, so he wants to approach the nearest square. How would I do that in unity c#?

Comment: if enttities have a low count use a list than loop through it via `Vector2.Distance` if it has many use the Culling Group api: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CullingGroupAPI.html.
Also im pretty sure this is a duplicate and you will find your answer if you look

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming Square is a MonoBehaviour
private Square FindClosestToPoint(Vector3 point, params Square[] allSquares) {
    if (allSquares == null || allSquares.Length == 0)
        return null;
    if (allSquares.Length == 1)
        return allSquares[0];
    float distToClosest = float.MaxValue;
    int indexOfClosest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allSquares.Length; i++) {
        Vector3 squarePos = allSquares[i].transform.position;
        float distanceToSquare = Vector3.Distance(point, squarePos);
        if(distanceToSquare < distToClosest) {
            distToClosest = distanceToSquare;
            indexOfClosest = i;
        }
    }
    return allSquares[indexOfClosest];
}
```

Calling from a MonoBehaviour works like

```
Square[] allAvailableSquares = [...] // implement logic on how to get the squares
Square closest = FindClosestToPoint(transform.position, allAvailableSquares);
```